# What does the phrase "space-warping portals" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Please help me figure out the meaning of the phrase "space-warping portals" in the following sentence from the description of the game "Levelhead":

> Play through hundreds of user-created challenges, like a mad dash
>   through a fireball gauntlet or wildly complex scenarios loaded with
>   space-warping portals. ([Apple's App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/story/id1501612854))

I consulted the [Word Reference dictionary](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/warp) for the meanings of the word "warp", but am not sure which of them fits here.

Comment: portals that change the shape of space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with "warping of space-time". The easiest real-world corollary would be if you were to place a heavy ball on a blanket. The ball warps (changes the shape) of the blanket, bringing parts to different distances to each other from where they were before. You can see a graphical representation of the warping effect caused by massive objects here, along with an explanation: https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/image/ligo20160211e

In fiction "warp drive" has been used for faster-than-light speed travel with various fictional implementations, but essentially they all try to change the "shape" of the space-time the vessel is traveling through, therefore shortening the travel time required.

In your example, the portals somehow distort the space they're in, allowing travel between two points that are not physically connected.